# iis deployment assembly load error

Tags: iis, deployment, assemblies, load

I get an error when I deploy my webpages in loacl IIS. The interesting thing is that "AjaxControlToolkit.dll" is present in the /bin directory.

Configuration Error 
    Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 250:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
Line 251:                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
Line 252:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 253:                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
Line 254:                <add assembly="Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />


Source File: C:\Program Files\ClearCanvas\ClearCanvas Image Server\web\web.config    Line: 252 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved the problem.

Please try [this](http://dotnetfish.blogspot.com/2007/10/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html)